# How do I remove decimal places from large doubles and get them to print as a number instead of 2.13837537957E14?

Tags: java, rounding

I am trying to round a large double (larger than ints allow) so it will print without decimal places to the E13 power, but I don't know how.

I've looked into DecimalFormat and casting and String methods to fix it and no answer has been for a number larger than an int can go.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
class Different { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,#########");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
            while(in.hasNext()) {
            double a = in.nextDouble();
            double b = in.nextDouble(); 

            double answer = (Math.abs(a - b));
            df.format(answer);
            System.out.println(answer);
            }
            in.close(); 
        }
    }
```

I want it to print

2
71293781685339
12345677654320

but get

2.0
7.1293781685339E13
1.234567765432E13

Comment: Quick answer here, probably far from the best one... Did you consider converting it to string and then removing the dots with replace methods?

Comment: `df.format(answer);` doesn't do anything because you don't save the result.

Answer (score 2):

Check the `Java API` for `System.out.printf()`.  Specifically it is described in the 
`PrintStream class`

```java
      double val = 123.4567765432092;
      System.out.printf("%3.14f%n", val);
```

Keep in mind that double values only have `53 bits of accuracy` including the integral part and the mantissa.  That equates to about `16` digits.  Any more than that and you will need to use `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the below code, it will convert double to long.

```
long answer = Double.valueOf(Math.abs(a - b)).longValue();
System.out.println(answer);
```